# Map arrays to hash with logical defined operator

Tags: perl

I am trying to set default value, if user doesn't supply it

Following is my code. Please point how it can be done with // operator

```
use Data::Dumper;
use Getopt::Long;
my @viewFiles = ("cdl", "lef", "verilog", "lib");
my %viewPaths;
my $pctDir = ".";
GetOptions(
  "pctDir=s" => \$pctDir,
  "cdl=s" => \$viewPaths{"cdl"},
  "lef=s" => \$viewPaths{"lef"},
  "verilog=s" => \$viewPaths{"verilog"},
  "lib=s" => \$viewPaths{"lib"},
);
@viewPaths{@viewFiles} //= ("$pctDir/cdl/topCellName.cdl", "$pctDir/lef/topCellName.lef", "$pctDir/model/verilog/topCellName.v", "$pctDir/model/timing/lib/topCellName.lib");
print Dumper \%viewPaths;
```

output is:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'cdl' => undef,
          'verilog' => undef,
          'lib' => './model/timing/lib/topCellName.lib',
          'lef' => undef
        };
```

Expected output:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'cdl' => './cdl/topCellName.cdl',
          'verilog' => './model/verilog/topCellName.v',
          'lib' => './model/timing/lib/topCellName.lib',
          'lef' => './lef/topCellName.lef'
        };
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The boolean operators and `//` operate on scalars, so their LHS is evaluated in scalar context. This means that

```
@viewPaths{@viewFiles} //= ...;
```

is equivalent to

```
$viewPaths{ $viewFiles[-1] } //= ...;
```

So instead, you need to do it per entry:

```
my @viewFiles = ("cdl", "lef", "verilog", "lib");
my %defaults; 
@defaults{@viewFiles} = ("pctDir/cdl/topCellName.cdl", "pctDir/lef/topCellName.lef", "pctDir/model/verilog/topCellName.v", "pctDir/model/timing/lib/topCellName.lib");

$viewPaths{$_} //= $defaults{$_} for keys %defaults;
```

However as an alternative - pre-filling the hash *should* work I think:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use Data::Dumper;
use Getopt::Long;
my @viewFiles = ("cdl", "lef", "verilog", "lib");
my %viewPaths;

@viewPaths{@viewFiles} = ("pctDir/cdl/topCellName.cdl", "pctDir/lef/topCellName.lef", "pctDir/model/verilog/topCellName.v", "pctDir/model/timing/lib/topCellName.lib");

GetOptions(
  "cdl=s" => \$viewPaths{"cdl"},
  "lef=s" => \$viewPaths{"lef"},
  "verilog=s" => \$viewPaths{"verilog"},
  "lib=s" => \$viewPaths{"lib"},
);

print Dumper \%viewPaths;
```

Comment: I may have to go with your first alternate.
Actually, there is dependency of variable `$pctDir` from user.
Is there any alternative without using loop

Comment: Why do you need to avoid using a loop? You're implicitly looping whatever you do, because that's the nature of the operation.

Comment: With `pctDir` being a variable (In case anyone's unclear - the original post had it as static text), then yes, you'll probably need to use the first example. Otherwise you'll end up with something nasty using `eval`.